# regex. How can I match the value between '+' and ':'?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string:

```
sometext +[value]:-
```

I would like to match the value(1-3 numerical characters) (with regex, javascript)

sometext may contain a +sign if i'm unlucky so I don't wanna end up with matching

```
some +text +value:-
```

I sat up last night banging my head against this, so I would be really glad if someone could help me.

Comment: Are the values within brackets as you've shown (your title and code conflict, unless of course stackoverflow removed the brackets from your title).

Answer (score 2):

If `sometext` contains a `+` but not numbers you can use the regex:

```
\+\d{1,3}:-
```

- `\+`: `+` is a meta char, to match a
  literal `+` we need to escape it as
  `\+`
- `\d`: short for `[0-9]`, to represent
  a single digit
- `{1,3}`: quantifier with `min=1` and
  `max=3`, so `\d{1,3}` matches a
  number with 1, 2 and 3 digits
- `:` : to match a colon
- `-` : to match a hyphen, its not a
  meta char outside a char class...so
  need no escape.

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit

If like you said in the post body (but unlike you said in the post title) you need to match sometext +[value]:-:

```
var result = "sometext +[value]:-".match(/\+\[(.*)\]\:-/i)
```

Result:

```
result[0] = "+[value]:-"
result[1] = "value"
```

---

#### Old answer

```
"some +text +value:-".match(/\+.*-/i)
```

The result is `+text +value:-`. It will match everything in +...here...-.

Answer (score 0):

Try anchoring your match to the end of the string:

```
/\+(\d{1,3}):-$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Get (multiple) values as array:

```
var input = "some +text +value:- +another_value:-";
input.match(/(?!\+)(\w+)(?=:-)/g) // ["value", "another_value"]
```

Or get the string if only one value is expected:

```
var input = "some +text +value:-";
input.match(/(?!\+)(\w+)(?=:-)/g)[0] // "value"
```